# Compiling python code while using PyGears framework

Tags: python, pygears

At the moment I'm writing my first code in PyGears and I'm stuck with part how to compile the code. Do I compile it like normal python code or I need some fancy tools?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to compile it like a normal Python code. If you are using python3 it should look something like this.

Let's say we have module **darken.py**

```
from pygears import gear
from pygears.typing import Ufixp, Uint
from pygears.lib import drv, collect
from pygears.sim import sim, cosim


@gear
def darken(din, *, gain):
    return din * Ufixp[0, 8](gain)


res = []

drv(t=Uint[8], seq=[12, 23, 255]) \
    | darken(gain=0.5) \
    | float \
    | collect(result=res)

cosim('/darken', 'verilator', outdir='./home/stefan/test/output')
sim()

print(res)
```

We can run a command inside a terminal

```
python3 darken.py
```

And output should be

```
-          /darken/mul [INFO]: Running sim with seed: 167830386130148172
0                      [INFO]: -------------- Simulation start --------------
103                      [INFO]: ----------- Simulation done ---------------
103                      [INFO]: Elapsed: 0.01
[6.0, 11.5, 127.5]
```